Migrate Room Database which has Stored User Data with Database that has New Table with Pre-populated Data
I have a database that lives in the assets folder. It contains pre-populated tables, as well as tables which store user entered data. Now, we have finished up another part of the app and are planning to unlock this section. The issue is that the database now contains new tables with pre-populated values.
How do I migrate the existing database with the new database, making sure to maintain the user entered data and the new pre-populated table values?
I have the following code, which correctly adds the new table to the existing database, but it does not retain the pre-populated data. I know I could use insert statements to add the pre-populated data, but that would be require hundreds of statements.
val migration1to2 = object: Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' ('id' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 'name' TEXT NOT NULL, 'specid' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('id' AUTOINCREMENT))")
    }
}

Room.databaseBuilder(context, InspectionDatabase::class.java, "inspection_db.db")
    .createFromAsset("inspection.db")
    .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
    .allowMainThreadQueries()
    .addMigrations(InspectionDatabase.migration1to2)
    .build()


In migrate function, you should open asset database and get all records from all tables in this db, then appends those to your db.

@anhtuannd so I would need to make a query in the dao to grab all data from all tables and then some sort of forEach loop to write this to database?

Yes, I think so. An alternative approach can be storing sql dump file instead of db file, and in migrate you just call execSQL.


I know I could use insert statements to add the pre-populated data, but that would be require hundreds of statements.

In the migration you could:-

Copy the asset database.
Open the copied asset database (inspeciton.db) as an SQLiteDatabase.
Extract the data from the copied asset database into a Cursor
Traverse the Cursor inserting the row as per the extracted data
close the cursor
delete the copied asset database

Something along the lines of:-
companion object {
    private var instance: InspectionDatabase?=null
    private lateinit var currentContext: Context
    fun getInstance(context: Context): InspectionDatabase {
        currentContext=context
        if ( instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,InspectionDatabase::class.java,"inspection_db.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .createFromAsset("inspection.db")
                .addMigrations(migration1to2)
                .build()
        }
        return instance as InspectionDatabase
    }
    val migration1to2 = object: Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            val assetDBPath = currentContext!!.getDatabasePath("inspection.db").path
            val assetInputStream = currentContext!!.assets.open("inspection.db")
            val assetDBSCHEMA = "ads"
            assetInputStream.copyTo(FileOutputStream(assetDBPath))
            assetInputStream.close()
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ('id' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 'name' TEXT NOT NULL, 'specid' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('id' AUTOINCREMENT))")
            /*

            database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '$assetDBPath' AS $assetDBSCHEMA")
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `users` SELECT * FROM ${assetDBSCHEMA}.users")
            database.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE $assetDBSCHEMA")
             */
            val assetDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(assetDBPath,null,0)
            val cv = ContentValues()
            val csr = assetDB.query("users",null,null,null,null,null,null)
            val idIx = csr.getColumnIndex("id")
            val nameIx = csr.getColumnIndex("name")
            val specidIx = csr.getColumnIndex("specid")
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                cv.clear()
                cv.put("id",csr.getLong(idIx))
                cv.put("name",csr.getString(nameIx))
                cv.put("specid",csr.getString(specidIx))
                database.insert("users",OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE,cv)
            }
            csr.close()
            if (File(assetDBPath).exists()) File(assetDBPath).delete()
        }
    }


Note that the commented out ATTACH cannot be used as the migration is within a transaction (ATTACHing the copied asset database would be simpler as can be seen).

see Additional for an example of ATTACHing BUT this is inadvisable due to the the need to end the passed transaction, to ATTACH, do the work, DETACH and then begin a transaction thus compromising the original transaction.


For brevity, the code was tested using the main thread.


Noting that getting the context this way is not ideal, perhaps se Access application context in companion object in kotlin
Alternative Pre Room
An alternative approach, could be to do the actual migration prior to providing control to Room.
This has the advantages that:-

the context passed/used is garbage collectable, and
that ATTACH can be used
that more comprehensive handling could be incorporated

BUT has the disadvantages:-

of always opening and then closing the actual database (to check it's version)

this could be minimised by just accessing the 4 bytes from offset 60 of the actual database file (the USER_VERSIO, which is what Room utilises). see Additional 2 for function that can read the  version from the header.


that the invocation, at least in the example, is undertaken when the @Database annotated class instantiated, rather than when an attempt is made to actually access the underlying database.

As an example consider, the following function:-
    fun migrateBeforeRoomHandling(context: Context,databaseNameRoom: String,assetName: String) {

        val actualDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(databaseNameRoom).path,null,0)
        val actualDBVersion = actualDB.version
        if (actualDBVersion == 1) {
            val assetSchema = "ads"
            val assetDBPath = context.getDatabasePath(assetName).path
            context.assets.open(assetName).copyTo(FileOutputStream(assetDBPath))
            actualDB.beginTransaction()
            actualDB.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '$assetDBPath' AS ${assetSchema};")
            actualDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `specid` TEXT NOT NULL);")
            actualDB.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users SELECT * FROM ${assetSchema}.users;")
            actualDB.setTransactionSuccessful()
            actualDB.endTransaction()
            actualDB.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE ${assetSchema};")
        }
        actualDB.close()
    }

and to appease Room's requirement for a Migration:-
    val dummyMigration1to2 = object: Migration(1,2) {
        override fun migrate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            /* DO NOTHING (done prior to room)*/
        }
    }

The above used in conjunction, for example, with:-
companion object {
    private var instance: InspectionDatabase?=null
    private lateinit var currentContext: Context /* LEFT IN TO SUIT co-existence of both methods */
    fun getInstance(context: Context): InspectionDatabase {
        migrateBeforeRoomHandling(context,"inspection_db.db","inspection.db")
        currentContext=context
        if ( instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,InspectionDatabase::class.java,"inspection_db.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .createFromAsset("inspection.db")
                //.addMigrations(migration1to2)
                .addMigrations(dummyMigration1to2)
                .build()
        }
        return instance as InspectionDatabase
    }


again, for brevity, the mainThread has been utilised

Note in both methods INSERT OR IGNORE has been utilised, this may or may not be suitable

Additional (circumventing the transaction passed to allow ATTACH)

The following alternative Migration works (allowing ATTACH) but negates the Migration being done within the passed transaction, which could compromise any changes applied prior to control being passed to the Migration:-
    val migrationAlt1to2 = object: Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            val assetDBPath = currentContext!!.getDatabasePath("inspection.db").path
            val assetInputStream = currentContext!!.assets.open("inspection.db")
            val assetDBSCHEMA = "ads"
            assetInputStream.copyTo(FileOutputStream(assetDBPath))
            assetInputStream.close()
            /* Cannot ATTACH whilst in a transaction, so end the transaction as passed to the Migration */
            database.setTransactionSuccessful()
            database.endTransaction()
            /* Can now attach the copied asset database */
            database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '$assetDBPath' AS $assetDBSCHEMA")
            /* Not sure of the ramifications of doing the table create and the inserts within a transaction */
            /*   could well need more complex handling */
            database.beginTransaction()
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ('id' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 'name' TEXT NOT NULL, 'specid' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('id' AUTOINCREMENT))")
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `users` SELECT * FROM ${assetDBSCHEMA}.users")
            /* Need to end the transaction to DETACH the copied asset database */
            database.setTransactionSuccessful()
            database.endTransaction()
            database.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE $assetDBSCHEMA")
            /* return with Room database in a transaction (not tested if actually required)*/
            database.beginTransaction()
            /* no need for the copied asset database, so delete it */
            if (File(assetDBPath).exists()) File(assetDBPath).delete()
        }
    }


although tested/working it is inadvisable to utilise this get-around.

Additional 2 (read version from a database's file header)
An SQLite (and therefore Room) database has a 100 byte header which includes the user_version, which is where the Android SQLite API and therefore room stores the version number.

as per https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header

As such reading the first 100 bytes allows the user_version to be extracted without the overheads incurred when opening the database as an SQLite database via the API.
This is a function that can do this and return the version as an Int:-
    private fun getVersionFromHeader(dbPath: String, noFileReturnValue: Int=-1): Int {
        var rv = noFileReturnValue
        val dbFile = File(dbPath)
        var userVersionOffset = 60
        /* Do not try if the database file does not exist */
        if (dbFile.exists()) {
            rv=0
            val istrm = FileInputStream(dbFile)
            val ba = ByteArray(100)
            istrm.read(ba, 0, 100)
            rv = (ba[userVersionOffset++].toInt() and 0xff shl 24) or
                    (ba[userVersionOffset++].toInt() and 0xff shl 16) or
                    (ba[userVersionOffset++].toInt() and 0xff shl 8) or
                    (ba[userVersionOffset].toInt() and 0xff)
            istrm.close()
        }
        return rv
    }


by default, if the database file does not exist, then function returns -1. This can be altered by passing the value wanted in this situation to the function.

e.g. it could be used by coding val versionFromFileHeader = getVersionFromHeader(context.getDatabasePath(databaseNameRoom).path)
